# how to find out the creation date of a file in c++

Tags: c++, windows, file

I'm new to programming. I need to find out the creation date of the files and sort by it. Please tell me what (library/framework) I can use to do this. Thank you

I tried to understand the filesystem library but I don't quite understand how to do it with its help.

Comment: There's always [fstat()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) to fall back on if for some reason [std::filesystem::last_write_time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time) doesn't work for you. Not many filesystems actually keep track of file creation times, just when a file was last written to.

Answer (score -2):

the `std::filesystem::last_write_time()` lets you check the file time last created.. and you can make function to sort files by time created

check out theses docs [last_time_write](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time) this function returns last modification time

```
 std::sort(filePaths.begin(), filePaths.end(), [](const fs::path& a, const fs::path& b) {
    return fs::last_write_time(a) < fs::last_write_time(b);
});
```

the sort function can be found in `algorithm` library
Here’s simple program to understand basic working

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {
    // Directory containing the files
    std::string directoryPath = "/path/to/your/directory";
// Vector to store file paths
std::vector<fs::path> filePaths;

// Iterate through the directory and store file paths
for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(directoryPath)) {
    if (entry.is_regular_file()) {
        filePaths.push_back(entry.path());
    }
}

// Sort file paths based on creation time
std::sort(filePaths.begin(), filePaths.end(), [](const fs::path& a, const fs::path& b) {
    return fs::last_write_time(a) < fs::last_write_time(b);
});

// Output sorted file paths along with their creation dates
for (const auto& filePath : filePaths) {
    std::cout << "File: " << filePath.filename() << " - Creation Time: " 
              << fs::last_write_time(filePath) << std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Creation time and last write time are not the same thing though.

Comment: No, last write time is when the file was last modified, not created

Comment: it a big coincidence that my chat bot spits out the same code with only minor modifications. I want to assume that you did not copy it but this is your content.

Comment: the std::filesystem::last_write_time returns last time midified